# Reputation log under Activity

Tags: feature-request, reputation

It would be great to see when and where we got Reputation under Activity tab.

An example would be:

**10m** *reputation* **+10** on [PHP Outputting Code in the Wrong Spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420838/php-outputting-code-in-the-wrong-spot)

This will come in handy, I sometimes see my Reputation going up and don't know where I got it from.

Answer (score 2):

You can click on the envelope just to the left of your name, and then the "reputation" tab. Click on "Today" if necessary, and it'll show you all the reputation you've gained in the day, and from which answers.

Comment: The envelope doesn't all ways show up. (When new reputation is added)

Comment: @Vlad.P: You can click on the envelope whether it's lit or not.

Comment: Oh, yes I feel stupid.